# I had follow someone code samples and try apply to my HighChart program but I can't get it work at all

Tags: javascript, json, highcharts

I had follow someone code samples, but I'm new to javascript and highcharts. In fact
this program worked but only shows one month at a time, I want show all the months' data. Sorry for my English. Could you give me some advice thanks.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var options = {
        chart : {
            renderTo : 'container',
            defaultSeriesType : 'column',
            rightMargin : 80
        },
        title : {
            text : 'the scholls'
        },
        subtitle : {
            text : 'data for 2012 years'
        },
        xAxis : {
            title : 'months',
            categories : []
        },
        yAxis : [{
                min : 0,
                title : {
                    text : 'students'
                }
            }, {
                linkedTo : 0,
                opposite : true
            }
        ],
        tooltip : {
            formatter : function () {
                return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>' + this.x + 'Months: ' + this.y + ' students:';
            }
        },
        legend : {
            layout : 'vertical',
            align : 'right',
            verticalAlign : 'top',
            x : -10,
            y : 100,
            borderWidth : 0
        },
        series : [{
                name : "students total",
                data : []
            }
        ]
    };

    //get the json files
    $.getJSON('http://localhost:3000/students/givemechart.json', function (data) {

        yData = options.series[0].data; //Array to store data for y column
        xData = options.xAxis.categories; //Array to store data for x column
        xDataObj = data[3]; //only can show one months
        yDataObj = data[3]; //only can show one totals

        // [[5, 2], [6, 3], [8, 2]]
        for (var key in xDataObj) {
            xData.push((xDataObj[key].month));
            console.dir(xData); //chrome console only
        }

        for (var key in yDataObj) {
            yData.push((yDataObj[key].total));
            console.dir(yData); //chrome console only
        }

        var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);

    });
});
```

This is one of my json files.

```
[
    {
        "student" : {
            "month" : 1,
            "total" : 24
        }
    }, {
        "student" : {
            "month" : 2,
            "total" : 27
        }
    }, {
        "student" : {
            "month" : 10,
            "total" : 96
        }
    }, {
        "student" : {
            "month" : 11,
            "total" : 1088
        }
    }, {
        "student" : {
            "month" : 12,
            "total" : 125
        }
    }

]
```

Comment: Very late to pick this up, but let me know if you're still struggling. If so, please try to describe what happens when you run the script. Are you getting an error?

Answer (score 0):

Set Min and Max for Xaxis like this :
 `xAxis : {
            title : 'months',
            categories : [],
min: 1,
max: 12
        }`

Comment: are you mean? don't need writing the code like
yData = options.series[0].data; //Array to store data for y column
        xData = options.xAxis.categories; //Array to store data for x column
        xDataObj = data[3]; //only can show one months
        yDataObj = data[3]; //only can show one totals

        // [[5, 2], [6, 3], [8, 2]]
        for (var key in xDataObj) {
            xData.push((xDataObj[key].month));
            console.dir(xData); //chrome console only
        }